# call emacs commande automatically

Tags: emacs, config, text-editor

I would find a way to execute the commands in the file emacs. Emacs and therefore automatically.
For example I often use: highlight-80
So I'm forced to type every time: Meta key + highlight-80 +-fashion

it's the same with linum-mode and plenty of other.

I have been trying to put in the file emacs.:
(highlight-80 +-mode)

But the option is not enabled.

Thank you in advance for your help. I am looking desperately for a moment, emacs is my working tool quotidient.

Regards

Comment: Edit your `~/.emacs` file

Comment: You may wish to consider using the built-in whitespace-mode instead, which offers a similar feature:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace

Comment: This is the page I would recommend, wrt different ways to highlight or otherwise notice lines that are longer than, say, 80 columns: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EightyColumnRule

Answer (score 3):

Use `C-h f` or `C-h v`, and read the Emacs manual about such choices.

Some of them are user options (variables), whose values you can customize, using `M-x customize-option`, so the default setting becomes what you want.

Others are modes, which you can call/set in your init file (`~/.emacs`) --- see the Emacs manual for how to do that. Typically, you use a positive number to turn a mode on and a negative number to turn it off.  E.g.: `(menu-bar-mode -1)` in your init file turns off the use of a menu bar.

In sum, the Emacs manual (`C-x r`) is your friend. Sit down and have a first chat with it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem generally a bit unsure about how customising Emacs works, so reading the manual on this topic should probably be your next step:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Customization.html

If you are not using the current stable release (Emacs 24.3 at the moment), there's a chance that some of that information will not apply. The in-built manual is, of course, always correct for the version you are running:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Customization` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: thank you so much for you answer, but it seems to be impossible. for example for the command highlight-80 +-mode it is not possible. i must use my keyboard for each lanch of emacs : M-X highlight-80 +-mode

Comment: I'm afraid `M-x highlight-80 +-mode` makes little sense to me, so I can't comment on that directly, and `(highlight-80 +-mode)` looks similarly bizarre. You seem confused about how customizing Emacs works, however, so pointing you at the manual's information on that subject seems valuable. As you've not linked to your `highlight-80` library, and you've really given no useful details about the failure, I'm not sure what else to suggest.